# Find columns with a specific word out of a list

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have a data frame in this format :

**Id comments**

```
23 triangles are not perfect 

43 angles are present

50 available together 

56 get them added
```

---

I want to extract columns which contain only the words 'angles' and 'get'

Expected Output:

**Id comments**

```
43 angles are present

56 get them added
```

---

Used this:

```
df_comments = df_comments[df_comments['comments'].str.contains("angles")]
```

but this returns (not getting exact matches)

**Id comments**

```
23 triangles are not perfect 

43 angles are together
```

Answer (score 2):

Use word boundaries by `\b\b` for get only exact matches with `|` for regex or:

```
L = ['angles','get']
pat = '|'.join(r"\b{}\b".format(x) for x in L)
df_comments = df_comments[df_comments['comments'].str.contains(pat)]
print (df_comments)
   Id            comments
1  43  angles are present
3  56      get them added
```